# How to fix bulma navbar dropdown when it is in the navbar-brand section

Tags: css, responsive, bulma

I am using the bulma.io framework to build my navbar.  I want to put a dropdown in the navbar-brand section but when I do it fails (expands the navbar) on smaller screens.  Is there a way to allow a dropdown menu in the navbar-brand section?

```
<nav class="topmenu navbar is-fixed-top is-dark" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
<div class="navbar-brand">
    <!-- LOGO -->
    <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
        <a href="/index" class="navbar-link">
            MyCompany
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-dropdown is-boxed">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="/one">One</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="/two">Two</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="/three">Three</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a role="button" class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="topmenu" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false">
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="topmenu" class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">
        <a class="navbar-item" href="/start">Start</a>  
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-end">
        <a class="navbar-item" href="/end">End</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: large screen]

[image: small screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Klaassiek I was able to get this to work.  Here is the final working CSS.

```
@media screen and (max-width:1023px) {
.navbar-brand .navbar-dropdown.is-boxed {
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-top: none;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(10,10,10,.1),0 0 0 1px rgba(10,10,10,.1);
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: calc(100% + (-4px));
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    transition-duration: 86ms;
    transition-property: opacity,transform;
}
.navbar-brand .navbar-dropdown {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-top: 2px solid #dbdbdb;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(10,10,10,.1);
    display: none;
    font-size: .875rem;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
}
.navbar.is-spaced .navbar-brand  .navbar-item.is-active .navbar-dropdown, 
.navbar-brand .navbar-item.is-active .navbar-dropdown.is-boxed, 
.navbar.is-spaced .navbar-brand .navbar-item.is-hoverable:focus .navbar-dropdown, 
.navbar-brand .navbar-item.is-hoverable:focus .navbar-dropdown.is-boxed, 
.navbar.is-spaced .navbar-brand .navbar-item.is-hoverable:focus-within .navbar-dropdown, 
.navbar-brand .navbar-item.is-hoverable:focus-within .navbar-dropdown.is-boxed, 
.navbar.is-spaced .navbar-brand .navbar-item.is-hoverable:hover .navbar-dropdown, 
.navbar-brand .navbar-item.is-hoverable:hover .navbar-dropdown.is-boxed {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.navbar-brand .navbar-item.is-active .navbar-dropdown, 
.navbar-brand .navbar-item.is-hoverable:focus .navbar-dropdown, 
.navbar-brand .navbar-item.is-hoverable:focus-within .navbar-dropdown, 
.navbar-brand .navbar-item.is-hoverable:hover .navbar-dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apparently bulma removes most of the styling from dropdowns when screens get smaller. It applies styles only to `min-width:1024px` then presumes you then want the dropdown to always be opened when screen get smaller than 1024px.

According to the [docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/):

> The navbar-dropdown is visible on touch devices < 1024px but hidden on desktop >= 1024px.

So what you could do 'to allow a dropdown in the navbar', is to apply the same bulma styles also for screens smaller than 1024px. Add this to your css and you will see that it fixes your problem:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1023px) {
    .navbar-dropdown.is-boxed {
        border-radius: 6px;
        border-top: none;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(10,10,10,.1),0 0 0 1px rgba(10,10,10,.1);
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        top: calc(100% + (-4px));
        transform: translateY(-5px);
        transition-duration: 86ms;
        transition-property: opacity,transform;
    }
    .navbar-dropdown {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
        border-top: 2px solid #dbdbdb;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(10,10,10,.1);
        display: none;
        font-size: .875rem;
        left: 0;
        min-width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        z-index: 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I still want the navbar-item to hide when it is in the navbar-start or navbar-end.  I have edited your answer slightly so that it only applies if the navbar-item is in the navbar-brand area.

Comment: even this does not quite work because the dropdown is not visible on small screens.